# Maven dependencies can't be resolved without proxy

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-2, maven-3

Maven can't seem to resolve the required dependencies.
The system isn't behind a proxy, so I can't see why it wouldn't be working:

```
C:\Program Files\Micro-Manager 64-bit\plugins\Micro-Manager>mvn install:install-
file -DgroupId=org.micromanager -Dversion=1.4.20-SNAPSHOT \ -Dpackaging=jar -Dar
tifactId=MMJ_ -Dfile=MMJ_.jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-w
ebdav-jackrabbit/1.0/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit-1.0.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.openspim:SPIMAcquisition:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Program Fi
les\Micro-Manager 64-bit\plugins\Micro-Manager\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-w
ebdav-jackrabbit:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to
 read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar
:1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit
:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.va
lidator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.cer
tpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to re
quested target -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
C:\Program Files\Micro-Manager 64-bit\plugins\Micro-Manager>mvn install:install-
file -DgroupId=org.micromanager -Dversion=1.4.20-SNAPSHOT \ -Dpackaging=jar -Dar
tifactId=MMJ_ -Dfile=MMJ_.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the keystore of your JDK does not contain the trusted certificates for maven central:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit
:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.va
lidator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.cer
tpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to re
quested target
```

Another possibility is that the plugin org.apache.maven.wagon is not in the pluginGroups inside the settings.xml

And the third guess would be that a plugin that copys files to webdav (the wagon plugin) as optional dependencies to org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit - you may need to add that dependency to the plugin.

But I think it's probably the keystore. There is a small Java class that helps you to import a certificate into a keystore: https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java - you can simply compile it with javac and run it using the remote url as paramter. It will create a keystore which contains the certificate.